# Can't clear the plot in my R shiny app

Tags: r, reset, shiny

I teach basic statistics at a local university and am trying to build an app where students can explore the relationship between scatterplots and the Pearson correlation coefficient. I can generate a blank plot and users can click inside the plot to generate points. As points are added a correlation coefficient is displayed. I can clear the map using a reset button; however, i cannot reset the previous points.

I tried assigning the list storing the points to NULL, but for the life I have no clue how to do it.

Any suggestion on clearing the graph so users can start over with a new scatterplot would be greatly appreciated.

A link to a 'working' app: https://uky994.shinyapps.io/ggplotcoords/

My code:

```
  `ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      actionButton("reset", "Reset!")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("graph", width = "100%", click = "plot_click"),
      verbatimTextOutput("click_info")
    )
  )
) 
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    output$graph <- renderPlot({
       plot(data$x, data$y, pch=data$values,col="white",xlim=c(0,100),
       ylim=c(0,100),xlab="X",ylab="Y")
    })
    points$x<-NULL
    points$y<-NULL
  })
  points <- list(x=vector("numeric", 0), y=vector("numeric", 0))
  data <- data.frame(x=c(0,100,0,100), y=c(0,0,100,100), 
                 values=c("A","B","C","D"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  # Visualization output:  
  observe({
    output$graph <- renderPlot({
      plot(data$x, data$y,
           pch=data$values,col="white",xlim=c(0,100),
           ylim=c(0,100),xlab="X",ylab="Y")
    })  
  })
  #v=input$plot_click$x
  # interaction click in graph  
   observe({
    if(is.null(input$plot_click$x)) return(NULL)
      print(points)
      points$x <<- c(points$x, isolate(input$plot_click$x))
      points$y <<- c(points$y, isolate(input$plot_click$y))
      output$graph <- renderPlot({
        plot(points$x, points$y,pch=20,col="#7fcdbb",xlim=c(0,100),
             ylim=c(0,100),xlab="X",ylab="Y")
      })
      output$click_info <- renderPrint({
        cat("Correlation is:\n")
        cor(points$x, points$y)
        #length(points$x)
      })
  })
})
shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)`
```

Comment: I think you don't need to have the plot within the observe function, and it should just work from the renderPlot{()} function. The instruction is that you only want to use observers for things which have side effects like clearing a data frame, saving a file and things like that. For rendering a graph you can just put it in the render function and Shiny will take care of all the updating.

Here's an Rstudio example that you can copy: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/dynamic-clustering.html

Comment: `points$x<<-NULL` ...

Comment: that works fantastically Shorpy. Thank you.